# How to fix error in windows10 Reinstall on ASUS R558U Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am trying to reinstall windows 10 pro on my Asus R558U Laptop and am facing trouble. I have done the following:

1. I created a win10 bootable USB using windows media creation tool.
2. Then I restarted my laptop and entered the boot menu and chose the USB option. 
   Then I followed this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=q9b6VqwA7vk
3. I followed the wizard instructions and clicked I dont have a product key.
4. Then I deleted all my partitions.

I now have 931.5GB of unallocated space on drive 0.
The wizard gets stuck

- when I create a new partition (of any size)
- when I just click Next after selecting the unallocated space

When it was stuck, I turned off my laptop and restarted it, I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upcv0.jpg), a partition of size 529.0MB is created and remaining is unallocated space. Now when I select this unallocated space or try to create a new partition, the wizard gets stuck again.

I also tried to create a new partition of 200GB and left the wizard on stuck mode overnight. In the morning I saw that there were two partitions of 529mb and 14mb and rest unallocated space. Amy further steps got the wizard stuck again.

I also tried using DISKPART tool. Everything works well till I attempt to clean the disk 0.
[check out Diskpart screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6NhR.jpg)
the error message is: '*DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error*'

After this when I try to list drives, the entire of 931GB is [missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXzT5.jpg). Although, it is visible again after a restart.

System Restore also doesn't work as I dont have any partitions.

I have also tried to create a bootable USB by downloading from Microsoft mirror and using Rufus, only to see similar results.

Kindly advise what I can do.

Comment: Your harddisk is broken and needs to be replaced.

Comment: oh. broken how? what could be the reason

Comment: There can be numerous reasons why a disk breaks. Some are explainable, some are not. Yours sound like a controller error though, something that is not common but also not uncommon, as in, other types or breakage happen more often, but the controller can still break. It is a chip and it can break for various reasons at any time.

Comment: could the reason be because of some loose connection? https://www.stellarinfo.co.in/blog/how-to-fix-the-io-errors-for-the-external-hard-disk-drives/

Comment: Again, there are many reasons it could be. A loose connection could also be the case, but its pure speculation. If a loose cable is the cause of the problem, it may have already damaged the controller in such way that reseating it won't fix it. But its pure speculation. Replacing the drive is definitely going to fix your issue though.

Comment: @AnshulJindal - I would agree with the conclusion you have already been told.  Your HDD has failed, the event leading up to your original reason to reinstall WIndows, was likely it starting to fail.  *It was only a matter of time, replace the HDD, and reinstall Windows.*

Comment: I see. Thanks guys!

Comment: **(1)** _`DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error`_ indicates a hardware failure, either with the HDD or HDD cable: disconnect power, remove battery, hold power button for 30s, then reseat the HDD cable on the motherboard and the HDD, and boot back to the installer. If the I/O error still occurs, try a known good HDD, and if that resolves it, warranty or toss the HDD. **(2)** If the R558U is UEFI, disable CSM mode in the UEFI firmware, as a 529MB partition is what's created for the BIOS boot partition, not an EFI boot partition.

Answer (score -1):

Windows installers are notorious for partition management. Use [Gparted](https://gparted.org/download.php) (the live version is the easiest) to create a new partition table (GTP will work), apply changes and reboot to windows installation again. That will clear the drive completely.

If that doesn't work you might have a faulty drive.

Comment: Linux should not be used to manage partitions on Windows, that's what `DiskPart` is for - to create a GPT partition table: `DiskPart` → `lis dis` → `sel dis #` → `clean` → `convert gpt` _(to open a terminal in WinPE [Windows installer]: `Shift`+`F10`)_; even if Gparted was used, it's not going to resolve an I/O hardware error.